# .htaccess rewrite url and query

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I couldn't find anything with the search so I'll try it here.

I need to make a rewriting rule (for a CMS) and additionally to avoid any bot or unwanted person to come onto the site i also want to set a custom token in the database which can be varied from site to site.

So for example a URL would look like this:

```
http://example.org/pageGoesHere/?token=kabaza
```

Now I need to get the page ("pageGoesHere") and the token separately, but the token must not be set all the time, as when the site is online, the token won't be needed anymore to access the page.

What I have tried so far:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} token=(.*)$
RewriteRule (.*) ./index.php?url=$1&token=$2
```

Whatever I try, it never returns me both the url and the token (if specified) as $_GET variable.

Hopefully anyone can help me to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your rewrite rule contains two backreferences ($1 and $2) but the pattern only has one set of parentheses. To match backreferences from the most recent rewrite condition, use %1

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} token=(.*)$
RewriteRule (.*) ./index.php?url=$1&token=%1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteRule (.*) ./index.php?url=$1
```

Edit: Just looking through [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) and I suspect this will work, though I've never used the [QSA flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) before:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteRule (.*) ./index.php?url=$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: Okay got that now working. Thanks for that already. But if i leave the query away, i'm getting a server error... Is there any way to fix that, too?

Comment: Since the URL wouldn't match without the token, the rules would not be applied. You could create a second rule, I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: Just edited my answer to include another possible solution, that's much cleaner, though I've no experience with it myself so take it with a grain of salt.